# Chef difference between resources and providers

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have went thru the Chef documentation to figure out the exact difference between the - resource and a provider but unfortunately I'm unable to comprehend the functional aspects of both or what exactly are they doing.

Can someone pls. explain in a simpler terms and an example would be really great. Thanks

I've came across the below in one of the recipe files

```
jboss10_dev "dev"  do
                    action :update
                        provider "jboss10dev_jboss_update"
                end
```

and I had no clue what it does.

Comment: I’ll write a longer answer tomorrow but roughly, you don’t need to know. The distinction only matters to Chef core devs and people diving very very deep into customizing Chef. We’ve mostly removed mention of providers in cookbook code.

Comment: @coderanger : Excellent.. Really appreciate your time here !! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, longer answer as promised. Roughly speaking the Resource is a value type. It contains all the data to describe the state of a thing, either desired state or current state. The Provider implements the action logic which is the agent behavior under promise theory. Or basically the Resource is the "what" and the Provider is the "how". That said, with the Custom Resource syntax we blur the lines a lot since you seem to be declaring action code in the resource, it actually just constructs a provider for you under the hood very quietly.

Comment: @ +1 Perfect .. one small clarification, w.r.t the above example would `jboss10dev_jboss_update` be a recipe file or ??

Comment: No, providers are their own thing still. But you would never put that line in a modern resource more or less (except with some of my poise cookbooks).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification